# Height don't work with two divs in float mode

Tags: html, css

I'm having a trouble with this question. It's very simple:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <section class="left">

    </section>
    <section class="right">

    </section>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div, section { border: 1px solid #000; }
.left { height: 100%; width: 200px; float: left; height: 200px; }
.right { width: 300px; float: right; height: 300px; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

Fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/H2c6g/

I have this two sections, and I need that both sections use 100% of avaliable height. I have a dinamic content on this two sections. Sometimes the right is larger, sometimes the left. Put a height just to explain, but in my real example, THERE ISN'T this fixed height.

Tks all.

Answer (score 1):

It's just not possible to use the same height if you don't know the height of neither the children nor the parent (because `height = 100%` would imply the full height of the next ancestor with a fixed height). However, there are few tricks.

Several solutions for the same height, from css-tricks:

> [Fluid Width Equal Height Columns](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

A working example in codepen:

> [Responsive Equal Height Divs](http://codepen.io/micahgodbolt/pen/FgqLc)

If you don't mind using javascript, also from css-tricks:

> [Equal Height Blocks in Rows](http://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/)

And some code, the first example from css-tricks. You have your html:

```
<div class="five-columns group">
  <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p></div>
  <div class="col"><p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS. In here, you simply make a vertical background so it *seems* like there's 100% height columns, even when there's not.

```
.five-columns { 
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
        linear,
        left top,
        right top,
        color-stop(0, #eee),
        color-stop(20%, #eee),
        color-stop(20%, #ccc),
        color-stop(40%, #ccc),
        color-stop(40%, #eee),
        color-stop(60%, #eee),
        color-stop(60%, #ccc),
        color-stop(80%, #ccc),
        color-stop(80%, #eee),
        color-stop(100%, #eee)
    );      
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(
        left, 
        #eee, 
        #eee 20%,
        #ccc 20%,
        #ccc 40%,
        #eee 40%,
        #eee 60%,
        #ccc 60%,
        #ccc 80%,
        #eee 80%,
        #eee 100%
    );
    /* Other vendors here */
}
```

Comment: Do not care if someone down your vote. just go on your way. i give +1. for your effort and spending time.

Comment: I don't take it personally but I care only to try to improve my answers and communication in general for the future. Thanks for that (:

Comment: Tks for the awswer, sorry about the down vote, really is very explained, but I don't understand how I apply in my case. It's a little complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fixed height you can use min-height for the divs containing dynamic content.
This way the div occupies atleat the minimul height you've specified but will take more height as the content's length.

```
div, section { border: 1px solid #000; height:100%;}
.left { min-height: 300px; width: 200px; float: left; height: 200px; }
.right { width: 300px; float: right; min-height: 300px; }
.clear { clear: both; }
```

This way your section will take 100% height, but the inner divs will take at least 300px height but will the heigh will automatically adjust when the contents are larger.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

You can make both sections be 50% in height of the containing div. That will make them both of equal height.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add a height of **100%** to the **html** and **body tags** to solve this problem

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2c6g/13/)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
div, section { border: 1px solid #000; height: 100%;}
.left { height: 100%; min-height: 100%; width: 200px; float: left;}
.right { width: 300px; float: right; height: 100%; }
```

Remove `clear:both` property without write atomatic wrap to next when its over flow.

---

Another way its also possible to set **div** element **height:100%;** to easily set **dynamic** **height** of **both div**,

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H2c6g/16/)**</kbd>

#### CSS

```
div{
    height:100%;
}
```

how this whould be help you!

Comment: Tks for your answer. It worked partially. this div has a margin-top and margin-bottom 20px, ie, no glue nor up nor down. With the first form, it works, but it passes through the container, ie not spelled the end of the container, it passes beneath him. Above it starts at the right corner.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to use `display: table-cell` to achieve this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <section class="left"> ... </section>
    <section class="right"> ... </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: table;
}
.wrapper section {
    display: table-cell;
}
.left {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
.right {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Cells in the row always try to adjust the height to conform the tallest one.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/H2c6g/14/